# Wordpress wp-admin redirects me to a different domain

Tags: wordpress, authentication, redirect

I go to `mysite.net/wp-admin.` 
Once I type in my username and pass word it redirects me to a blank page with address of

`mysite.co.uk/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.net%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

I own both domains mysite.co.uk and mysite.net.
in fact mysite.co.uk redirects to mysite.net

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Go to your  database, and find the table called wp-option, then change the wordpress address and site address to mysite.net.

You can also add the following lines of code to the wp-config.php-file

```
define('WP_SITEURL','http://your-site-url.com');
define('WP_HOME','http://your-site-url.com');
```

Comment: After using this config solution you can log in to wp-admin and change the db settings on the General Settings page (/wp-admin/options-general.php). Apparently the config overrides the db values so once logged on, remove the config settings, then update the General Settings values.

Comment: my wp-config.php doesnt have these 2 lines

Comment: @bubakazouba What prevents you from adding the "these 2 lines"?

Comment: Sometime you will need to update wp_option table row with the key: "wordpress-https_ssl_host"

Answer (score 1):

The above answer didn't work for me.  See:

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179788/107311 by [James](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/68366/james)
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

> change "siteurl" and "home" in the database table "wp_options"
>   (through phpMyAdmin or similar)