# wordpress wp-admin redirects to another domain name

Tags: php, wordpress

Our wordpress site was recently hacked - there's still something left over though and I can't find out how it's happening.

http://www.whatgoesaroundstore.co.uk/wp-admin/ is ok

http://www.whatgoesaroundstore.co.uk/wp-admin redirects to some spanish site.

What might have changed that I've missed??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**See blewo url**

[Wordpress wp-admin redirects me to a different domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456360/wordpress-wp-admin-redirects-me-to-a-different-domain)

**Or try it:-**

Go to your database, and find the table called wp-option, then change the wordpress address and site address to mysite.net.

You can also add the following lines of code to the wp-config.php-file

```
Define('WP_SITEURL','http://your-site-url.com');
Define('WP_HOME','http://your-site-url.com');
```

Comment: see also http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wwwdomainnamecomwp-admin-redirects-to-different-site

Comment: thanks - the "see also" link actually solved my problem. There was extra code in the .htaccess which redirected to the spanish site.