# Wordpress clone on Dreamhost

Tags: wordpress, dreamhost

So I created a new subdomain on Dreamhost. One-click installed Wordpress. Fresh Copied the olddomain.com to newdomain.com exported all the tables with the drop attribute to the new wordpress database via phpmyadmin. Then followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8456463) post to update the urls.

The site doesn't load, giving me this error message:

```
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, the wp-config.php file was also updated to connect to the new db as opposed to the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up creating an empty site and then using the [WP Duplicator](http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugin. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure to check the 'www' rules in Fully Hosted (from the web panel: Manage Domains > Web Hosting > Edit), compared with your site URL settings in the WordPress dashboard. Make sure those aren't conflicting first.

If you need further assistance, just let me know the domain name and I can take a look. Please also feel free to start a LiveChat from the panel or submit a ticket; our support team is here to help 24/7!

Thanks!

Ellice S

DreamHost Staff

Comment: Cannot reach the wordpress dashboard, because I can't reach wp-admin.